# How to create a JPA derived query that does not return a full record?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Lets say I have a simple table that is accesses by derived JPA queries.

```
name | age | job
----------------
sam  | 40  | IT
sue  | 37  | BU
tri  | 62  | BU
ria  | 28  | IT
tom  | 55  | CO
```

All derived queries I have today return a list of rows (findBy...).

Is it possible to have a derived query that returns a list of strings?

I would need a list of all possible jobs.

```
SELECT job FROM mytab GROUP BY job;


--
IT
BU
CO
```

That would be a list of strings.

But not sure how to do that with derived queries - if even possible.

Comment: May be [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-group-by) part of hibernate documentation will be useful for you.

Comment: Derived query does not support `Group By`. You can use `@Query`, `Specification` or `Querydsl` to do that.

Comment: Can I use Query that is not returning a list of records but a list of strings??

Comment: @chris01 Yes you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

As far I found out recently the easiest way in me eyes (without new entities, repositories, ...) is a native query with @Query.

```
public interface MyRepo extends JpaRepository <MyRecord, Long>
{   
    // all my other interface-methods
    List <MyRecord> findByNameAndAge (String name, Integer age);  // just for a sample
    

    @Query (value = "SELECT hint FROM my_record GROUP BY hint", nativeQuery = true)
    List  <String> listHints ();
}
```